# wxPython. SpinCtrl. Pop-up warning

Tags: wxpython, python-3.4

There is an object wx.SpinCtrl:

```
self.m_spinCtrl_width = wx.SpinCtrl(self.panel, -1, self.width, style=wx.SP_ARROW_KEYS | wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER, max=max_)
```

This object has such a feature that if the parameter min >= 0 (in the code is not specified, only max is specified), then when you try to enter something different from the number in the widget, a warning flashes:

[image]

Can I somehow generate this warning myself? For example, I need the value of the object "m_spinCtrl_width" to be less than 0, but then the object allows to enter both letters (and any other characters) in the widget, I would like to track that if the user entered a number, then issue a warning.

Sorry for my English.

Comment: I think the answer to the question: wx.adv.RichToolTip.

Comment: Which version of wxpython are you using. I am unable to input `letters (and any other characters) in the widget`. Only `-` and `+` are allowed. I'm using 4.0.1 (Gtk3) and 4.0.3 (Gtk2)